# Eclipse Console Error That JAVA_HOME Is Missing

Tags: java, eclipse

In the Eclipse console, I'm getting an error that JAVA HOME is not set.

I went ahead and set it to `.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_02\` in system variables
Then I restarted eclipse, but I keep getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the period and semicolon from the beginning, like this:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_02\`
This is just one specific directory, not a semicolon-separated list like the system PATH variable.
Also, make sure the environment variable you create is called JAVA_HOME with an underscore between JAVA and HOME.  You seem to have JAVA HOME with a space between them.

Comment: Removing the period semicolon at the start did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the jre inside the eclipse.

Go to Window -> Preferences

Java -> installed JREs

Comment: Under installed JREs, I can already see it there, so I guess it's already been added for me, unless there are some specific additional setups I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Create JAVA_HOME environment variable points to your JDK directory, don't put it into PATH variable.

Comment: but I don't have a JDK directory. My `ProgramFiles/Java` directory only contains the `jre1.6.0_02`